# Failed to set user defined inspected property Swift Storyboard

Tags: swift

I've created a subclass for `UIView` and want to update a keypath using the storyboard. I've done this in the Storyboard:

[image]

which I felt should update the property in my CustomView:

```swift
class CustomView: UIView {
    var isDataLoaded: Bool!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

but I get the error

```swift
Failed to set (isDataLoaded) user defined inspected property on (RuntimeAttributes.CustomView): [<RuntimeAttributes.CustomView 0x7fdb67e07cd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isDataLoaded.
```

So how can I set this keypath in the `UIView`?

Comment: Try marking your property as @objc

Comment: Hmm. This can remove the error, but the property is set as nil (If I mark the property as @objc and as String)